# How to populate value 'qty' key of one array based on the 'id' key of another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two variables. `$inventoryOfCategory` and `$myInv`. The two arrays are like the following:-

```
$inventoryOfCategory = array(
                           [0] => array(
                                      'id' => 1,
                                      'title' => 'Book'
                                  ),
                           [1] => array(
                                      'id' => 1,
                                      'title' => 'Copy'
                                  ),
                           [2] => array(
                                      'id' => 1,
                                      'title' => 'Pen'
                                  ),
                       );

$myInv = array(
                  [0] => array(
                            'id'  => 1,
                            'qty' => 10
                         ),
                  [1] => array(
                            'id'  => 3,
                            'qty' => 20
                         )
         );
```

The `id` on each row is unique. Now, I want to load the data of `$inventoryOfCategory` in a table. On each row, there will be a checkbox, the name of the `inventoryOfCategory` and a textbox. When the id of each `$inventoryOfCategory` in each row will match with an id of `$myInv`, the checkbox will be checked and the textbox will contain the `qty` of the $myInv corresponding to the `id`. Here is my following code:-

```
<?php
if(isset($inventoryOfCategory) && !empty($inventoryOfCategory))
{
    foreach($inventoryOfCategory as $inventory)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="inventory[]" value="<?php echo $inventory['id'];?>" <?php if(array_filter($myInv, function($item) use($inventory) {return $item["id"] === $inventory['id']; })) echo "checked";?>/></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $inventory['title'];?></b></td>                               
    <td><input type="textbox" name="inventory_qty[]" class="form-control" style="width: 120px;" value="<?php if(array_filter($myInv, function($item) use($inventory) {if($item["id"] == $inventory['id']) echo $item["qty"]; }));?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

The data are saved accurately, and hence the checkboxes are checked accurately. The problem is with the `qty` value that are populated in the textbox.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <?php 

    if(isset($inventoryOfCategory) && !empty($inventoryOfCategory))
    {   $i=0;
        foreach($inventoryOfCategory as $inventory)
        {
         $qty= $myInv[$i]['qty'];
         $id= $inventory['id'];
         $title= $inventory['title'];

         //HERE you can put your existing TR and use above values


        $i=$i+1;
        }
    }

    ?>
```